# How to organize many crawler functions?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I build a little statistics service with Laravel. I crawl some sites and get stats from there for my application. For example I get the subscriber count from YouTube and Twitter.

```
public function getYouTubeStats() {}
public function getTwitterStats() {}
public function getFacebookStats() {}
...
```

So right now I have one controller with 20 or 30 functions where every crawler needs his own function because obviously every external site is different. But I don't think such a large controller is good for future development. So my question is how could I organize this?

I could make an own controller for every crawler. But I can't get the functions from other controllers in my main crawl-controller. For example I need the function *getStats()* from *YouTubeController* in the *MainCrawler* controller. I don't think there is an easy way to do this?

Or should I make a new Model for every service?

```
$youtube = new YouTubeStat::getStats();
$twitter = new TwitterStat::getStats();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar project and I've created a Controller for each social network.

Then on your MainCrawler you could say `$stats = (new YouTubeController)->getStats();`

And if you have similar functions in your social network controllers, you should use a [Trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

Comment: Ok, yeah I think one Controller per service is a good solution. Thanks for your advice.